# why this "for loop" works instead of overflows

Tags: c, arduino

This is a part of code in an arduino SPI communication instance.

```
char c;
for (const char* p = "Hello, world!\n"; c = *p; p++){
SPI.transfer(c);
Serial.print(c);
}
```

it will output “Hello,world!” in serial port and SPI. But why `c = *p` can judge whether this char string is ended or not? Normally we use the

```
int k;
char p[]="hello world!";
for (k=0; k < strlen(p); k++){
SPI.transfer(p[k]);
Serial.print(p[k]);
}
```

Comment: Look up "null terminator"

Comment: The value of `c` is zero at the end of the string. In C, zero is read as false in a Boolean expression context.

Comment: This code would be a perfect example of "posing". Someone writing needlessly obscure and dangerous code just to flash their knowledge of mildly useful C features. And that's why the last S in the "KISS principle" is there. The correct way to write the loop is this: `const char* p = "Hello, world!\n"
for (int i=0; p[i]!='\0'; i++){ SPI.transfer(p[i]); Serial.print(p[i]); }`. Everthing else is just nonsense. The `strlen` version is fine as far as readability goes but might be needlessly slow if used with bad compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before explaining, you have to understand a few things:

- Characters (i.e., a `char` type) can be treated as a number without any cast based upon its ASCII encoding
- Strings in C always end with a NUL terminator. Importantly, this character has a numerical value of 0 (i.e., when you treat it as a number, it's equal to zero).
- Boolean values don't really exist in C independant of an integer representation. Zero is treated as "false" and anything else is treated as "true".

With this out of the way, let's look at what's happening in the loop.

First, we have a pointer `p` that points at the *first* character of the string `"Hello world!\n"` (this is coming from the statement `const char* p = "Hello, world!\n"`).

At the top of the loop, we check our loop condition, which is `c = *p`. Note that this assigns the value pointed at by `p` into `c`, and assignments in C evaluate to the value that's been assigned. What that means in this context is that our test is essentially just `*p`.

Since booleans don't exist in C, `*p` is false only when the character pointed at by `p` has a value of zero. This can only happen when `p` is pointing to a NUL terminator, which is always at the end of a string in C. Therefore, our loop will stop when we've hit the end of our string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I know when the *p pointed to the end of that char string, *p=\0. Then c=\0, at this time the "for loop" condition is not met, so it jumped out.

Comment: Glad I could help! If this answered your question, then please mark this as the solution :)

Comment: Booleans do exist in C but they aren't used by control statements (as in C++).

Comment: There is no need to mention ASCII in this; C implementations are not required to use ASCII, and the code in question works regardless of whether ASCII is used or not. Strings in C always end with a null character, which is not necessarily the ASCII `NUL`. Boolean values do exist in C; the `_Bool` type was added in 1990.

Comment: Re “assignments in C evaluate to the value that's being assigned”: Assignments in C evaluate to the assigned value. For example, after `int x;`, the value of the assignment `x = 3.5` is the assigned value, 3, not the value being assigned, 3.5.

Comment: @EricPostpischil good point! I've edited my post to reflect that, good catch on my poor wording 

Comment: Re: Booleans in C, `_Bool` is an integer type (large enough to hold 0 and 1), and I'm speaking with reference to languages like Java where boolean values are defined independently of an underlying integer value